# Exhibit an example of a vector space $V$ with non-equal subspaces $U_1, U_2, U_3$ such that $U_1 \oplus U_3 = U_2 \oplus U_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give me a hint? Not an answer.

Exhibit an example of a vector space $V$ with non-equal subspaces $U_1, U_2, U_3$ such that $U_1 \oplus U_3 = U_2 \oplus U_3$.

$\oplus$ means direct sum.

How does $U_1 \neq U_2$ if $U_1 \oplus U_3 = U_2 \oplus U_3$?

Comment: In general, the sum of subspaces $A+B$ is not the same thing as the sum of vectors in the vector space $a+b$, because the sum of subspaces $A+B$ is defined as the set of ALL possible sums $\{\alpha+\beta\,: \, \alpha\in A, \beta\in B\}$. For example, if $A\subset V$ is a subspace then $A+A=A$, because subspaces are closed under addition. This is why the "cancellation law" doesn't hold when you're dealing with the subspaces.

Comment: Hint: Decartes's system of coordinates for the plane did not require the two axes to be perpendicular to each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the usual vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}.$ Let $e_{1}=(1,0)$
and $e_{2}=(0,1)$. Let $U_{1}=\mbox{span}\{e_{1}\},$ $U_{2}=\mbox{span}\{e_{1}+e_{2}\}$,
and $U_{3}=\mbox{span}\{e_{2}\}$, then $U_{1}\oplus U_{3}=U_{2}\oplus U_{3}=V$.

Comment: OP's very first sentence says they do not want an answer